# passing string array from java to C with JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a string array like `{"myname","yourname","hisname"}` and I am trying to send this array to *C* with using *JNI*. I could not find any clear solution for this. I have tried to take this string as a `chararray` but no success.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can write a simple function that takes a `jobjectArray` object, cast each one to jstring and then call `GetStringUTFChars` on it.

Like this:

```
void MyJNIFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray stringArray) {

    int stringCount = env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);

    for (int i=0; i<stringCount; i++) {
        jstring string = (jstring) (env->GetObjectArrayElement(stringArray, i));
        const char *rawString = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);
        // Don't forget to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` when you're done.
    }
}
```

Comment: is the ```jobject object``` input required?

Comment: Do I need to call `DeleteLocalRef` on the temporary `jstring` object returned by `GetObjectArrayElement`?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a way.  You would pass the `String[]` into your native method from the Java side and that would come across to the C/C++ side as a `jobjectArray`.  You would then use `GetObjectArrayElement()` to get a `jstring` at a given index and then use `GetStringUTFChars()` or `GetStringChars()` to get a C/C++ pointer to the underlying string data.

And if you don't know about it, the [JNI Book](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/download/jni.pdf) is a valuable reference.

Comment: thx for reference. I read it. I solved my problem with sending string to C side. I tried sending array for practice and have success. Thx for help. There are two correct answers and if you don't mind, I wanna give rep to 8ball ...

Comment: The link to "JNI Book" is broken.

Answer (score 0):

it can be done in following way:

```
(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray prdctini)
    {
        const char *param[20];
        jsize stringCount = (*env).GetArrayLength(prdctini);

          for (int i=0; i<stringCount; i++) {
                  jstring string = (jstring) (*env).GetObjectArrayElement( prdctini, i);
                  param[i] = (*env).GetStringUTFChars( string, NULL);
          }
          cout<<"U_Id="<<param[0]<<endl;
          cout<<"aggregation="<<param[1]<<endl
}
```

Comment: How about `ReleaseStringUTFChars` ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember to use

```
env->GetArrayLength(stringArray);
```