# JNI pass parameters to method of c++

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a c++ file myCppTest.cpp which has method

```
int myFunction(int argv, char **argc) {
}
```

and 
a Java native method in myClass.java

```
public native int myFunction (int argv, char[][] argc);
```

After generate the header file using javah -jni myClass, i have the header

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JPTokenizer_init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jobjectArray);
```

In my myClass.cpp, I defined

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JPTokenizer_init
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint argv, jobjectArray argc) {
        //need to call int myFunction(int argv, char **argc) in myCppTest.cpp 
}
```

How could I pass the arguments "jint argv, jobjectArray argc" to "int argv, char **argc", thanks.

EDIT:

I THINK I MADE A MISTAKE

The Java native method in myClass.java should be

```
public native int init (int argv, char[][] argc);
```

So there is

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_myClass_init
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint, jobjectArray);
```

generated after javah.
And in myClass.cpp, i have

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_myClass_init
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint argv, jobjectArray argc) {
        //need to call int myFunction(int argv, char **argc) in myCppTest.cpp 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct mapping between Java objects and C++ primitives, so you will have to convert the arguments that are passed by the Java runtime environment, and then call your function.

Java will call `Java_JPTokenizer_init` -- this is where you perform your conversion and invoke your "plain old" C++ function.

To convert the array of strings, you will first need to access the array, then the individual strings.

- For array access, see [`GetObjectArrayElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetObjectArrayElement).
- For string access, see [`GetStringUTFChars()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#GetStringUTFChars).

Comment: I know this is old, but neither of these links work. It would have been better to put a snip-it of the code required along with the link (in case the links break).

Comment: I think there is no such thing as a jstringArray so you need to use jobjectArray.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#:~:text=out%20of%20memory.-,GetObjectArrayElement,-jobject%20GetObjectArrayElement(JNIEnv

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#:~:text=of%20the%20string.-,GetStringUTFChars,-const%20char%20*%20GetStringUTFChars


Explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5972254/10183099

Comment: @Craig Links fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object of the class and invoke method just like any other C++ code.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_JPTokenizer_init
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint argv, jobjectArray argc) {
      myClass obj;  //create object of the class you want
      obj.myFunction((int) argv, (char *) &argc); //call the method from that object
}
```

Comment: Nick, I made a mistake in the original question.

Comment: Do you have argc and argv juxtaposed above?

Comment: Doesn't creating the myClass object `myClass obj;` override the second parameter of the function declaration of type `jobject` and throw an error since the types don't match?..

Comment: This answer is untested rubbish. You cannot successfully cast from `jobjectArray` to `char*`. You have to call `env->GetObjectArrayElement()` and then `env->GetStringUTFChars()`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I need to access a native library I use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) instead of JNI. Normally JNA is much easier to set up than JNI so you might want to give it a try.

Cheers,
Felipe

Comment: Thanks, but JNI has to be used in my case.