# writing a JNI wrapper around a C main function

Tags: java-native-interface

I have to write JNI wrappers around existing C source codes so that they can be called from Java. But most of the C source codes take in command line arguments (argc and argv) and use them extensively. Is there any way that I can pass the string args[] that I capture in Java, to the C function with very minimal changes to the C source file?

I believe that as part of the JNI wrappers, I have to write a function in C that is called by the Java code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing string array from java to C with JNI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972207/passing-string-array-from-java-to-c-with-jni)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For sure, you'll have to write a C function called by the Java code.

As seen in the answer pointed to by Radiodef, that function will receive a `jobjectarray`, as a java `String[]` is represented in `jni` as a `jobjectArray`.

In the function, you will have to malloc a C arrays, for storing all the char* pointers that your legacy `main` function is expecting in it's `char **argv` argument.

You will store in that array malloced pointers, in order to be able to release the JNI objects immediately. You may avoid those malloc, but at the cost of storing JNI resources in another array for further release, so I don't think it's a goo idea.

Remember that the convention for legacy main functions is that the first arg (index 0) is the 'program name'. You will have to fake it.

```
void MyJNIFunction(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobjectArray stringArray) {

    // Get the number of args
    jsize ArgCount = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, stringArray);
    // malloc the array of char* to be passed to the legacy main
    char ** argv = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(ArgCount+1)); // +1 for fake program name at index 0
    argv[ 0 ] = "MyProgramName";

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < ArgCount; ++i ) {
       jstring string = (jstring)((*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, stringArray, i));
       const char *cstring = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, string, 0);
       argv[ i + 1 ] = strdup( cstring );
       (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, string, cstring );
       (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, string );
    } 

    // call the legacy "main" function
    LegacyMain( ArgCount + 1, argv );

    // cleanup 
    for( i = 0; i < ArgCount; ++i ) free( argv[ i + 1 ] ); 
    free( argv );
    return;
}
```

Comment: Using `GetStringUTFChars` assumes that the LegacyMain function can take the _modified_ UTF-8 encoding of the Java Unicode string. It would be better to know which encoding and character set it expects and convert to it in Java using `String.getBytes(...)`.

Comment: @TomBlodget you are right. Not sure if I must update. Is my code working just fine with plain old ASCII 7bits args?

Comment: It looks like it would but I can't think of any system that uses full ASCII and only ASCII. Program arguments are often file system paths. I can't think of any file system that uses ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget OK. I will update with some disclaimer about encoding issues.

Comment: Are you missing a bracket at the end of the following line, just before the semi colon? for( i = 0; i < argCount; ++i ) free( argv[ i + 1 ];

Comment: @mick Indeed, thanks. Will update tomorrow,  but you can do it now.

Comment: One other quick note - I think that (env*) should maybe be (*env)? It compiles for me like this. I'll let you make the changes just to be safe!