# How to use JNI to call a "main" function that takes an array of character pointers?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, program-entry-point

hi i have an c function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

and my wrapper.c has this function

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_package_Class_lameMain(JNIEnv *env, jclass class, jint argc, jcharArray argv) {
    return main(argc, argv);
}
```

and in java i've defined it like this

```
private native int lameMain(int argc, char[] argv);
```

but i think i'm doing something wrong with the argv-argument... it's not an char-array, but a array of char-pointers.

can anyone help?

when i run it my app crashes with

```
03-20 23:26:23.487: A/libc(30436): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xfd90001d (code=1), thread 30436 (package)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Java side, convert the array to an array of strings (i. e. `String[]`). Pass it like that. On the JNI side, go through the array and retrieve the characters of each string. The declarations would go like this:

```
private native int lameMain(String[] argv);
```

And in C:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_package_Class_lameMain(JNIEnv *env, jclass class,  jobjectArray argv )
```

There's no need to pass argc, because Java arrays store their own size.

That said, you're probably doing something very wrong. Typical Android programs don't start with `main` and don't take command line arguments - they have activities instead. A C `main()` function is a starting point of a program, but since you're calling it from the Java side, it's not the first thing in the program.

EDIT: Okay, but I still think you're doing this wrong on more than one count. I take it, the encoder takes a file - right? So you save the wave from memory into a file *just to be read again*? That's lame (pun intended).

Also, do you really need to pass an arbitrary sized array from the Java side? If you know the number of arguments at design time, and it's small (say, two), it's much, much easier to just pass two `jstring`s.

Anyway, here goes the array stuff. This assumes the sources of your JNI library are C++, not C. For C, the invokation of JNI functions would be slightly different, and you'd have to use malloc/free instead of new/delete.

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_package_Class_lameMain(JNIEnv *env, jclass class,  jobjectArray jargv)
{    //jargv is a Java array of Java strings
    int argc = env->GetArrayLength(jargv);
    typedef char *pchar;
    pchar *argv = new pchar[argc];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        jstring js = env->GetObjectArrayElement(jargv, i); //A Java string
        const char *pjc = env->GetStringUTFChars(js); //A pointer to a Java-managed char buffer
        size_t jslen = strlen(pjc);
        argv[i] = new char[jslen+1]; //Extra char for the terminating null
        strcpy(argv[i], pjc); //Copy to *our* buffer. We could omit that, but IMHO this is cleaner. Also, const correctness.
        env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(js, pjc);
    }

    //Call main
    main(argc, argv);

    //Now free the array
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
        delete [] argv[i];
    delete [] argv;   
}
```

Comment: hi thanks.. i'll try that, i want to call the main function of the lame-encoder frontend, to avoind writing my own wave-parser etc.. it seems to work if i hardcode the argv-array in my wrapper.c but not as java-argument until now... i'll try

Comment: could you explain closer how i convert the jobjectArray to "char *argv[]" ?

Comment: `GetStringUTFChars` will work for many characters but in general C functions would not like _modified_ UTF-8 encoded strings. Call  `GetBytes()` or `GetBytes("UTF-8")` on the `java.lang.String` instance and then copy to a buffer and NUL-terminate it.

Comment: But, if you're going to use modified UTF, `GetStringLength` is *not* the number of bytes `GetStringUTFChars` needs. Use `GetStringUTFLength` instead.

Comment: Point taken; fixed. The OP is probably doing it wrong, anyway. I'm answering the question, but I feel the OP's task can be accomplished easier.

Comment: thanks.. got it working.. unfortunately l4ame doesn't serve the functionality i need =( (concat mp3 or wave files correctly) .. i'll try to get ffmpeg working for my androidd project ^^

Comment: What is the difference in the invocation of JNI functions?

Comment: Difference between what and what?

Comment: between C & C++.   Could u write the code that suit C.

Comment: @miraclemo This answer gives a C example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20273537/334402