# Send parameters from Java to C code in JNI environment

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am working on building a tool in Java. I need to integrate a big C project with my Java project. So I am using JNI.

I thought that, If I create a new C class that exactly does the same thing with the main class of the project (new C class would be in JNI style), and call it in Java code; I would be able to run the whole C project. I hope I am clear so far.

Here is the class that is supposed to the same things with main class of the C project:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_CallExact_C_1Main(JNIEnv *, jobject, 
          jint, jobjectArray) {

 PomdpSolveParams param;

 //**argc** should be replaced with **jint**
 //**argv** should be replaced with **jobjectArray**
 param = parseCmdLineAndCfgFile( argc, argv );  

 showPomdpSolveParams( param );

}
```

Can anybody tell me how to replace the variables argc and argv with correct parameters?

Comment: First of all, you have to convert jobjectArray of j.l.String-s to a C array of char*. And then, yes, you may call an equivalent of int main(int argc, char* argv[]) if needed. I would suggest to use a tool like [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) to automate all those boring C<->Java issues

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258134/writing-a-jni-wrapper-around-a-c-main-function and feel free to upvote if that's what you were looking for.