# How can I send multiple strings from android Java to JNI?

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972207/passing-string-array-from-java-to-c-with-jni)

I have declared the JNI function as

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_mypackage_myapp_MyJavaClass_Fun(JNIEnv* env, jobject object, jobjectArray stringArray)
```

And the corresponding Java function in `MyJavaClass` is declared as:

```
public native void Fun(String[] strArray);
```

But its not working for me as I keep getting run time error:

> No implementation found for void com.mypackage.myapp.MyJavaClass.Fun(java.lang.String[])

I have also tried declaring `Fun` as

```
public native void Fun(List<String> strArray);
```

And

```
public native void Fun(ArrayList<String> strArray);
```

but these also result in same run time error

Comment: Does your log show that the JNI library is loaded successfully? Can you call some other native method?

Comment: Show us your System.loadLibrary() call

Comment: Also ensure that there are no overloads for `Fun()` in java code.

Comment: I found the mistake. I was calling `Fun()` before `System.loadLibrary()` was being called. Thanks @samgak. But I am wondering is there a way to avoid this? Right now the `System.loadLibrary()` is being called in `onResume()`. Can this be called in `onCreate()` instead?

Comment: put it in a static initializer for the class